# can i insert different object/text in each indesign page automatically

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have to insert a different sentence for each day of the year in a diary and it is possible to do this without having to go sheet by sheet?

Comment: Yes, just make a text box thats threaded thru the pages and put a section break after each sentence